# Pass functions from radio buttons

Tags: r, shiny

I'm creating a shiny app with functions that depends on radio buttons. I tried to set them in the *choices* argument of the radioButtons function. Here is an example of what I'm trying to do, in the ui.R:

```
radioButtons("action",label=h3("Action"),
    choices=list(
        "Sum"=sum,
        "Mean"=mean))
```

And I got the next error:

> ERROR: 'match' requires vector arguments

I know I could use the *switch* function in *server.R* to set the functions, but I would like to do something like this:

```
lst=list("Sum"=sum,"Mean"=mean)
lst[[1]](x)
lst[[2]](x)
```

Which of course works fine in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do something like this. Names and values of the list passed as a `choices` argument are rendered as a HTML and do that, have to be converted to `character`, and values returned from created input are `characters` as well. Using lookup table is a pretty match the only reasonable option.

An alternative would be to use `choices=list("Sum"="sum", "Mean"="mean")` combined with `eval(parse(..))` but in this case **it is a really bad idea**, since it gives an user an ability to execute arbitrary R command on a server.